# Trouble installing Mono on RPI. Libmono-corelib4.5-cil error

Tags: mono

My setup at the moment is RPI zero2w running Bullseye.

I installed Mono from the mono-project download page.

On installation it seems to freeze on libmono-corelib4.5-cil the Pi becomes unresponsive.  On restart the Pi won’t update and asks me to run Sudo dpkg —-configure -a.

On doing this it tried to download the libmono-corelib4.5-cil again and gets me into the continuous loop of fail.

It seems to happen a lot and only way to fix is to wipe and start again.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Allan

Install mono without any errors

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ If you read about its stories, then probably you can let it rest.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.